# PHP - Fat Free Framework - Named URL Routing in Subfolder - 404

Tags: php, apache, fat-free-framework

**Situation**

I am trying to implement named URL routing into my webapp based on the Fat Free Framework version 3.4.

The project I am working on is located in a subfolder, /foo
So I access the project through localhost/foo

This works nicely, I can also access different URL routes without any issues.

**Problem description**

When I access a route in a template it gets rendered as `<form method="POST" action="/do/stuff">`
With the leading '/' the browser interprets it as the start of the webserver and therefore takes me to localhost/do/stuff instead of localhost/foo/do/stuff

**Code**

This is how I pass a named route into a template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ 'doStuff' | alias }}">
```

This is an example from my routes.ini

```
POST @doStuff: /do/stuff=Views->doStuff
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteRule ^(tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

apaches mod-rewrite is enabled.
I feel like I have missed something important, but I have been trying for two days to get this to work, without luck. Any leads would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alias()` function returns a URL relative to the web app, not to the web root. Therefore, you should prefix it with the web app `BASE`, like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ $BASE }}{{ 'doStuff' | alias }}">
```

Comment: D'oh. The solution is so simple, yet I was too blind to see it. Thanks a bunch :)!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `<head>`

```
<base href="{{ @SCHEME.'://'.@HOST.@BASE.'/' }}">
```

It sets the browser's default base and appends every url, even if it contains a `/` to it.

Comment: I had already set the following
`<base href="<?php echo $SCHEME.'://'.$HOST.':'.$PORT.$BASE.'/'; ?>" />`

But I replaced it with your code, unfortunatley it didn't fix the issue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code doesn't work, if you're using the template engine. You code only works with the view class. Did you check your source code iin the browser? Does the URL look properly in the header?

Comment: Which code do you mean exactley? I changed my base attribute to yours, and it's now outputting `<base href="http://localhost/foo/">` into the page source, which is the location the webapp is located at. Unfortunatley when accessing named routes I still get routed to the root of the webserver (e.g. localhost/do/stuff instead of localhost/foo/do/stuff)